# Код Java на Scala

Tags: java

Хочу уточнить вопрос про использование классов и библиотек написанных на java в языке scala. Что необходимо сделать чтобы можно это сделать? Импортировать? Можно ли потом в классе scala писать на java?

Comment: Решение действительно простое: при импорте в фаил scala библиотек и классов java  их легко использовать напрямую...

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать любые библиотеки типа .jar в своем проекте, если их использование не вызывает конфликтов версий. Т.е. импортирование jar обычно является достаточным условием для их использования. Также, некоторые IDE (например, Intelij Idea) позволяют в одном проекте (но не в одном файле) совмещать открытый код Java и Scala.

Использование пакетов на Java в Scala совпадает с использованием пакетов Scala в Scala. А вот на Java использовать код Scala менее удобно из-за добавления различных префиксов в названии.